# Return only a part of a page from document.getElementById().innerHTML=req.responseText, Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have build a combobox, and when I change it I use a function in onChange. I use here `document.getElementById().innerHTML=request.responseText`

But my problem is that it return all the content of the file qytetet.php, but I want to return only the string "The first phase", not the other string.

This is the function in the file index.php:

```
function filtroQytet(rrethiId) {        
    var strURL="qytetet.php?rrethi="+rrethiId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            // only if "OK"
            if (req.status == 200) {                        
                document.getElementById('qytetidiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("Ka nje problem ne perdorimin e XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }               
    }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

And the `'qytetidiv'`, is also in the index.php file like below:

```
<tr>
    <td> Qyteti </td>
    <td><div id="qytetidiv">
        <select name="qyteti">
            <option>Zgjidhni rrethin me pare</option>
        </select></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

While qytetet.php is:

```
<?php
    $rrethi=intval($_GET['rrethi']);
    include('connection.php');
    $query="SELECT Id_qytet, Emri_qytet FROM qytetet WHERE Id_rrethit='$rrethi'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="qytetet" onchange="filtroNivelin1(this.value)">
    <div id="prova">
        <option>The first phase</option>
    </div>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value=<?=$row['Id_qytet']?>><?=$row['Emri_qytet']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<br />
<select name="niveli1">
    <option>The second phase</option>
</select>
```

So I want that only the string "the first phase to appear", not the string "The second phase". How can I  modify `document.getElementById('qytetidiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;` to return only a part of the qytetet.php, not all the content?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this is done by sending a [selector after the url to the load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (scroll down to "Loading Page Fragments". Here's the source code of how they do it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js#L62

If you want to do the same thing yourself, without using jQuery, you can load the whole document, and use `document.queryselector` to get the part you want.